# Using Report Builder 3.0 to create a "Difference Report" based on historical report data

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm pretty new to SSRS and the Report Builder so hopefully this isn't too stupid of a question and that it makes sense.

My company is trying to automate some reports that we have been having to do manually thus far. The one that is giving me difficulties is a "Difference Report". Basically we generate a report that has the current data for this particular week. This data is copied into our Difference Report template in a section for Current Report.

Then we find the report from last week and copy last week's "Current" section into this week's "Previous Report" section. Once that is done, there is a third section that compares the two sections and displays what sections have changed and the count of the changed differences.

What I am wanting to do is to automate that particular process. So is there a way that I can pull data from a snapshot of the report into the "Previous Report" section alongside current data from the database? I have searched the internet and haven't been able to find anything yet.

If this sort of thing can't be done, then that is fine as well. It's better to know one way or the other. Your guys' help would be absolutely amazing. Thank you all in advance. Let me know if there is anything I can do to help clarify anything.